# Python sum array of objects into objects

Tags: python

I have a list (name=carpet) of objects type mini_carpet.
Mini_carpet contains a list of objects called packages.
Packages has various properties, the one interesting to me is nr_buys.

What I want to do is to sum the various nr_buys that are within a mini_carpet, within a carpet.
This is what I have done so far:

```
for d in range(0, carpet.__len__() - 1, +1):
nr_total = sum(carpet[d].packages[i].nr_buys for i in carpet[d].packages)
```

This is giving me an error because list indices must be integers.
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: `carpet.__len__()` oh god... Please, use `len(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, it's generally better to loop directly over the items in a list, rather than looping indirectly using indices. It's easier to read, and more efficient not to muck around with indices that you don't really need.

To get a total for each `mini_carpet` you can do this:

```
for mini in carpet:
    nr_total = sum(package.nr_buys for package in mini)
    # Do something with nr_total
```

To get a single grand total, do a double `for` loop in the generator expression:

```
nr_total = sum(package.nr_buys for mini in carpet for package in mini)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in range(0, len(carpet) - 1, +1):
nr_total = sum(carpet[d].packages[i].nr_buys for i, _ in enumerate(carpet[d].packages))
```

You want to get the `indexes` of a `dict`, so use `enumerate`, which returns a `tuple`: `(index, item)`.
Also, why are you using `dict.__len__`?

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this, which I feel is more Pythonic, is:

```
nr_total = sum(package.nr_buys for package in carpet[d].packages)
```

The difference, as stated above, is that calling `for x in list` in python gives you the items of the list, and not their indices. That means that the `i` in your answer is not the integer index in `packages` of your item, but your item from `packages` itself, which you can use directly.

Now this can be done from the start:

```
nr_total = sum(package.nr_buys for mini_carpet in carpet for package in mini_carpet)
```

(don't ask me why Python uses that order, it confuses me as well, but that's how list comprehensions work.)

Answer (score 0):

> sum the *various* `nr_buys` that are within a mini_carpet, within a carpet

Asides what others have said about trying to index your list with a non integer object, you're also throwing away the result of previous iterations.

You can use a mapping/dictionary to keep these results using the carpet index as the key, which can later be used to access the result of the sums of `nr_buys` values of the packages in that carpet:

```
nr_total = {}

for i, c in enumerate(carpet):
    nr_total[i] = sum(package.nr_buys for package in c.packages)
```

To get the total `nr_buys` for all the carpets, you'll simply do:

```
total = sum(nr_total.values())
```

Answer (score -1):

When you've already coded the __len__ method, u dont need to call it by `carpet.__len__()`. Instead of use `len(carpet)`.

Comment: Agreed, but that doesn't answer the question.